# Is It necessary to keep all jsp files under WEB-INF folder when developing a SpringMVC web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was learning SpringMVC but currently facing one problem.
All my jsp files are under /WEB-INF/jsp folder.
During a form submission I try to return a new page success.jsp if registration going to be succesfull else failure.jsp.
My problem is Although message's were displaying but the url din't get changed.Is it the same as it were during form request.`http://localhost:8080/Twitter/User?new`
After succesfull for submision I want it to be `http://localhost:8080/Twitter/Success.jsp`.
I am able to achieve this when I put my jsp folder outside Web-inf.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that by redirecting from your server. And its not about putting your .jsp files under any folder. Displayed url is about where data is getting from. You cant change it by forwarding or redirecting or using `ModelAndView`.

Comment: I do not want my form action to be accessed directly,So I think I need to put it under /web-inf/jsp and then try to perform redirection to show success page..

Comment: Then use : response.sendRedirect(url)